# MySQL time ranges exluding overlapping ones

Tags: mysql, datetime, overlap, overlapping

| id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 2021-08-07 15:25:10.000000 | 2021-08-10 15:25:10.000000 |
| 8 | 2021-08-09 15:25:10.000000 | 2021-08-12 15:25:10.000000 |
| 9 | 2021-08-19 15:25:10.000000 | 2021-08-22 15:25:10.000000 |
| 10 | 2021-08-21 15:25:10.000000 | 2021-08-25 15:25:10.000000 |

[image]
I have time data overlap like this. What i have to do is take the beginnings and endings without counting the ones in between and calculate the gap in between. So the result i expect from here is

| start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-08-07 15:25:10.000000 | 2021-08-12 15:25:10.000000 |
| 2021-08-19 15:25:10.000000 | 2021-08-25 15:25:10.000000 |

I wrote a simple query like this, but the result and the difference are wrong, what should I do? (my table contains only id, start_date and end_date)

```
SELECT *,TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(end_date, start_date)) / 3600 AS Total
FROM (
  SELECT   DISTINCT *
        ,(SELECT MIN(start_date) FROM deneme
          WHERE end_date BETWEEN t.start_date AND t.end_date) AS TIME_ENTER
        ,(SELECT MAX(end_date) FROM deneme
          WHERE start_date BETWEEN t.start_date AND t.end_date) AS TIME_EXIT
  FROM deneme t
  ) AS o
GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Comment: @ysth 10.4.20-MariaDB

Comment: Can you illustrate your table data more accurately? Show us how the result table data would look like if you run `SELECT * FROM deneme`.

Comment: @FaNo_FN Thanks for the suggestion, I edited it.

Answer (score 0):

**An idea:**

List out the min and max dates where there are no records then use that to separate between before and after (the no records date range) as a separate group.

*For full breakdown, please refer this fiddle link : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=d366ff58efc1f520132ed7cd81d729de

The breakdown:

1. Generate a range of dates based on existing data in the table. Fortunately, MariaDB 10.4 supports window function of [WITH RECURSIVE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/recursive-common-table-expressions-overview/), therefore it's easy to generate the date ranges once you understand how `WITH RECURSIVE` works:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   SELECT MIN(start_date) AS dt, MAX(end_date) AS mxdt FROM deneme UNION ALL
    SELECT dt+INTERVAL 1 DAY, mxdt FROM cte WHERE dt+INTERVAL 1 DAY <= mxdt)

SELECT * FROM cte;
```

2. Use the generated date ranges and `LEFT JOIN` it with table `deneme` and get only the dates where there are no records, get the `MIN()` and `MAX()` date of those:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   SELECT MIN(start_date) AS dt, MAX(end_date) AS mxdt FROM deneme UNION ALL
    SELECT dt+INTERVAL 1 DAY, mxdt FROM cte WHERE dt+INTERVAL 1 DAY <= mxdt)
    
SELECT MIN(dt) min_no_record, MAX(dt) max_no_record
FROM cte 
LEFT JOIN deneme d1 ON dt BETWEEN d1.start_date AND d1.end_date
WHERE d1.start_date IS NULL;
```

3. Make the query above as subquery and `CROSS JOIN` it with table `deneme` again but this time use a `CASE` expression to assign each date that exists before and after the non-existent record period:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   SELECT MIN(start_date) AS dt, MAX(end_date) AS mxdt FROM deneme UNION ALL
    SELECT dt+INTERVAL 1 DAY, mxdt FROM cte WHERE dt+INTERVAL 1 DAY <= mxdt)
    
SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN d.end_date < min_no_record THEN min_no_record
            WHEN d.start_date > max_no_record THEN max_no_record
            ELSE 0 END
FROM deneme d 
CROSS JOIN   
(SELECT MIN(dt) min_no_record, MAX(dt) max_no_record
FROM cte 
LEFT JOIN deneme d1 ON dt BETWEEN d1.start_date AND d1.end_date
WHERE d1.start_date IS NULL) v;
```

*The part of `... THEN min_no_record` or `... THEN max_no_record` in the `CASE` expression can be anything.  You can define it as `... THEN 1`  or `... THEN 2` but it's up to you.

4. And finally, get the `MIN()` and `MAX()` date of the group. The `CASE` expression from above is used in the `GROUP BY` instead; omitted from `SELECT`:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
    SELECT MIN(start_date) AS dt, MAX(end_date) AS mxdt FROM deneme UNION ALL
    SELECT dt+INTERVAL 1 DAY, mxdt FROM cte WHERE dt+INTERVAL 1 DAY <= mxdt)
 SELECT MIN(d.start_date),
        MAX(d.end_date)
   FROM deneme d 
    CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT MIN(dt) min_no_record, MAX(dt) max_no_record
     FROM cte 
     LEFT JOIN deneme d1 ON dt BETWEEN d1.start_date AND d1.end_date
   WHERE d1.start_date IS NULL) v
GROUP BY CASE WHEN d.end_date < min_no_record THEN min_no_record
            WHEN d.start_date > max_no_record THEN max_no_record
            ELSE 0 END;
```